# Small issue with Javascript Toggle effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am having a small issue with a 'toggle' feature I'm trying to implemt into my website.

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bqJhL/).

Here is my jQuery so far:

```
$('#more').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('.texto').toggle();
    $('span#buttonone','#more').toggle();
    $('span#buttontwo').css('display','block');         
});
```

When I click 'Read More', I'd like to change the text to say 'Hide' and vice versa. Currently, as you can see from the demo, it is breaking & showing both at the same time.

I've a feeling I may be over-engineering this and it's probably a lot simpler than I've made it.

Can some kind gent/lady help out a little? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqJhL/3/)

No need to select it by ID when they have the same class, or set the CSS when you're using `toggle()`:

```
$('#more').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('.texto, .a-btn-text').toggle();          
});
```

Comment: Got to wait 10minutes @Zenith - that's how fast you are!! ;-D Thank you so much for taking the time to help out here - if I can overcomplicate things, I always tend to :) Great work!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest reducing your HTML, and using the following:

```
$('#more').on('mousedown', function () {
    $('.texto').toggle();
    $('#moreLess').text(function(i,t){
        return t.trim() == 'Read More' ? 'Hide' : 'Read More';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bqJhL/5/).

With the following HTML:

```
<p>
    <a id="more" class="buttons a-btn">
        <span class="a-btn-symbol">&gt;</span>
        <!-- combined the two buttons -->
        <span id="moreLess" class="a-btn-text">Read More</span>
    </a>
</p>

<div class="texto">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Similarly, for extensibility, I'd suggest changing the HTML to the following (primarily changing from `id`s to using `class`-es:

```
<p>
    <a class="more" class="buttons a-btn">
        <span class="a-btn-symbol">&gt;</span>
        <span class="moreLess" class="a-btn-text">Read More</span>
    </a>
</p>

<div class="texto">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<p>
    <a class="more" class="buttons a-btn">
        <span class="a-btn-symbol">&gt;</span>
        <span class="moreLess" class="a-btn-text">Read More</span>
    </a>
</p>

<div class="texto">
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$('.more').on('mousedown', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        parent = self.parent();
    parent.next('.texto').toggle();
    parent.find('.moreLess').text(function(i,t){
        return t.trim() == 'Read More' ? 'Hide' : 'Read More';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bqJhL/6/).

Comment: Good answer, David! Will take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: Why not just set the text for the button programmatically..? http://jsfiddle.net/bqJhL/7/

Comment: Primarily, @Mr.Polywhirl, because I didn't see it as a particular advantage. But yeah, it's not a bad idea.